# How to change the scroll direction of mouse on Mac mini?

Tags: mouse, macos

How do I change the scroll direction of a USB mouse on a Mac mini using Ventura? On my MacBook, there is a setting **System Preferences** > **Trackpad** > **Scroll & Zoom** but I cannot find this on a Mac mini.

[image: Screenshot of macOS Venture Appearance settings]

Comment: Same question on laptop with Ventura 13.4

Comment: -> [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/464521/how-to-change-the-scroll-direction-of-mouse-on-laptop-with-ventura)

Comment: You're in the wrong section. It's in Mouse, not Appearance - https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Enhf.jpg

Answer (score 2):

If I understand the question correctly, the following works on my 2017 27" Retina 5k iMac running macOS 13.1 Ventura:

Go to "System Settings...-->Mouse-->Natural scrolling" and flip the switch to the way you like it.

Successfully tested using an old USB wired Apple "Mighty Mouse".  It should work the same on a Mac mini, although I don't have one to test with (nor do I have a non-Apple wired USB mouse).
Also, be sure to scroll all the way down in the "System Settings..." window in order to see the "Mouse" option...

Comment: Welcome to [apple.se]! I fear the question author doesn't see the 'Mouse' option in System Settings, otherwise it'd be relatively obvious.

Comment: Maybe if you make note in your answer that the OP is in Accessibility and not in the Mouse settings pane.

Comment: I have gone through all the mouse options as well. It just isn't there. Is this an issue specific to Mac mini? it doesn't have a built-in trackpad or mouse like MacBook Pro. In fact on the Mac mini there is no System Settings > Mouse

Comment: morpheus - it's hard to prove a negative, but search 'mouse' rather than 'scroll' & see what you find. See https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/464525/85275