# How can I change the scroll direction of the mouse on a laptop with Ventura?

Tags: mouse, settings, ventura, macos, mouse-keys

I have a laptop with macOS 13.4 (Ventura) and cannot find how to modify the scrolling direction of a USB mouse: not under **Mouse** nor under **Accessibility** in **System Settings**.

<sub>(This question is related to [How to change the scroll direction of mouse on Mac mini?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/452971/how-to-change-the-scroll-direction-of-mouse-on-mac-mini).)</sub>

Comment: Can you get a screenshot of Mouse? It's there on an iMac - https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Enhf.jpg

Comment: OK, I did not know it was called "Natural scrolling". It worked! Can you repeat your comment as an answer, please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's in Mouse - the linked question shows an image of Appearance instead - & is called Natural scrolling.
When it's 'on' it acts like scrolling the screen on an iPad, 'off' is what a traditional mouse user with a scroll-wheel would expect.

[image]